# pass mouse click from From2 to Form1 c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I made a secondary form when I display a few labels, when I click outside the form (inside the primary form) the form close but the primary form is not focused, I have to press 2 more clicks in the form to be focused.

Primary form

```
    private void btn_Notifications_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NotiCenter notiForm = new NotiCenter();

        notiForm.Show(this);
    }
```

Secundary form

```
    private void NotiCenter_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainUI MainForm = GetFormOwner();

        this.Close();

        MainForm.Focus();
    }

    private MainUI GetFormOwner()
    {
        MainUI MainForm = (MainUI)this.Owner;

        if (MainForm == null) throw new Exception("Form owner not found");

        return MainForm;
    }
```

I use a buttom to show the form and I use Deactivate event to close the form.
When I click in the primary form, the secondary form close but the primary form ignore the click in any control in the primary form;

Another question, the buttom in the primary form is show like Im holding the click in the buttom after I display the form

[Primary and Secundary form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRu7i.png)

Comment: MainForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MainForm.Focus()));

Comment: @HansPassant ty, that help with the second question and some of the issue with the first one; now I only need a way to send the mouse click location to the primary form

Comment: What means send the mouse click location to the primart form. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737882/getting-mouse-coordinates-on-mouse-click) can help you?